# Couldn't play music/video on Google Pixel 3a (Q Beta 5)

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk, android-10.0

I'm building an music android app, when i tried to build an apk file and install it on Google Pixel 3a so app can start normally, but couldn't play music/video but when build it from Android Studio so music/video can play normally.

So why that issue happen ? 
Is the apk file error or is this a limitation of Q Beta ?

Please help me to find out solution for that issue

Comment: probably some problem with a proguard? do you have it enabled? Also show how you play it

Comment: How to know what i missed in proguard file ?

Comment: first check if it is caused by it by disabling proguard